# Is it okay to have all related columns in single table? Can select query for multiple table affect performance?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, select, insert

I designing my database where i was wondering if is it okay to have all related columns in single table, however, my concern is all the columns will not be filled at the same time. They will be filled as the results are obtained or as the process changes. I can have two options for that.

**Option 1**: Initially I run insert query for that single table, which inserts a record for columns related to process 1 (and null in other columns) and then, update query for the same record to replace that null values with actual values for columns related to process 2.

**Option 2:** To have two tables(for process 1 and 2) and insert records data (linking them with primary key) as process proceeds.

Which option has better performance while inserting the data?  INSERT+UPDATE in one table or INSERT in two tables. The columns are highly related.

Also, I am not sure...if selecting from the same table will be faster or selecting from two tables or it is the same. I will require to access the data for process 1 and 2 very frequently.

Which option will be good, performance-wise? I am using MySQL.

Comment: Selecting from two tables requires a join, which is more expensive than selecting from one table.

Comment: Yes, because of join, a single table is preferable. Though, can storing values by option 1 actually works or it can increase cost? Because UPDATE(to best of my knowledge) usually does DELETE+INSERT, but what it does while updating null values. Option 1 can be expensive? or it should not matter actually?

Comment: If process 1 and process 2 always happen for every PK value, I would lean toward option 1; but without knowing specifics of the data (types) stored or the use pattern, it is kind of a guess. If you must insert/update the data as fast as possible, but can afford slower joins, option 2 could be better; and with appropriate indexes, the cost of joins can be greatly mitigated. That said, updates are not _that_ expensive so this starts sounding like premature micro-optimization.

Comment: Thanks @Uueerdo This gives a good clarification.

Comment: `REPLACE` does `DELETE` + `INSERT` (and will lose the old auto_increment id, if present).  `UPDATE` does not.

Answer (score 1):

From performance perspective, single table is the best option. To get the data from two different tables will require join and it will slow down the performance. However, it all depends upon the data usage from table like data.
Sometime, to improve performance denormalization is the best option.

From better organization perspective, it is good to split the data into two tables. It indicates for which type of data the table is updated. Or in better word the purpose of table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your opinion. About data, all the columns in table are related and I will need to access different set of columns for different purpose. The concept of de-normalization for performance is noteworthy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or REPLACE into one table is faster than two inserts. SELECT from one table is faster than SELECT from two tables with a join even if that join is well optimized. So if your application always accessed all of the data in a record, you should have one table.

However, if your application usually accesses only a small subset of the record, and your reads are much more frequent than your writes (a very common scenario), then you are better off splitting the record into two tables because your common case (read a small subset of the fields) will be improved   significantly as your data size grows - enough to offset the extra overhead of the less frequent writes and full record reads.

This will be of particular significance when the size of the entire dataset exceeds the amount of the physical memory where it is likely to be cached. Then in the two table scenario you can still grow let's say by a factor of 10, and your common case - small column subset access - is still mostly reading from RAM, while in the one record scenario you are already starting to read from disk even when you need only a few columns thus resulting in a factor of 1000 or so difference in performance.

Comment: Yes, the application often access a small subset of record, and sometimes might require to access all the data in the record (for displaying a summary). So, I think as I will be having - small column subset access more over full records, splitting the tables should be the choice. The number of reads and writes are more likely to be the same as each process have so many columns. Thanks for explaining the difference.